# Data on who offered bounties

Tags: support, bounties, users, data-dump, api

Is there a way to know who offered bounties on each question on SE? We are working with the SO datadump, and there is data there on bounties in the `Votes.xml` file. However, there is no information on which user offered each bounty. Is there a way to obtain this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *should* be. Votes are anonymous, but an exception is made for bounties. For an example, see [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/729992/last-100-bounties). According to the [schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/295232):

> #### Votes
>
> ...
>
> - UserId (only present if VoteTypeId is 5 or 8)

(vote type 5 = Favourite, 8 = BountyStart)

Comment: Thanks, but where does it say UserId (only present if VoteTypeId is 5 or 8)? When I look at the readme file from the data dump it says only when VoteTypeId  is 5. That is, on this page:
https://ia800500.us.archive.org/22/items/stackexchange/readme.txt

Comment: @splinter that information is not up-to-date. The BountyAmount is also included for VoteTypeId 8 (see the query I linked to), not just 9. I've also linked to the SEDE schema which *is* (AFAIK) up-to-date.

Comment: Exactly. I wonder if the site managers are aware of the information in the readme of the datadump is not up to date. But just to confirm - the SEDE schema pertains to the SE datadump as well?

Comment: Yes, it's even advertised as *Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE*. The community keeps it up-to-date, but is unable to do so for the readme.txt in the dump.

Comment: We could really do with an indication in the schema answer where there are differences. Not all tables mentioned in the schema are in the dump. I never really checked for the columns but I'm sure the business rules apply. Maybe we need Nick or Jeremy to confirm if the source of SEDE and the dump is the same so we can only focus on structure differences.

Comment: Thanks @rene, is there some place where I can track the development on your suggestion - confirming if the source of SEDE and the dump is the same?

Comment: @splinter keep an eye on the schema answer I would say

Answer (score 2):

"Bounty start" votes (votes in the `Votes` table with `VoteTypeId = 8`) will indicate who started the bounty. In the data dump, it might look like this:

```xml
<row Id="1037" PostId="132" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="43" CreationDate="2016-01-15T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="50" />
```

The `UserId` there is of the user offering the bounty. You can [verify this on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/iot/query/729990), and even if the user doesn't come back to award the bounty, the correct `UserId` will still be noted, as they had to offer the bounty in the first place.

Comment: But in the readme file it says that UserId is populated only if `VoteTypeId=5`. I am referring to the readme from the data dump.

Comment: @splinter In that case, the readme is mistaken. I took that line of XML that I'm using to demonstrate directly from the data dump, so you should have no trouble.

Comment: Indeed you right - I just confirmed the readme I referred to is mistaken, as both you and @Glorfindel claimed!